# Dask: TypeError: __call__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: dask

I am experiencing this error using Dask. I have no idea about how to go about fixing it, as it doesn't seem to be anything in my code explicitly.

What I am doing is reading a dataframe and using `stanfordnlp` to tokenize a text column, and then take out the `nouns`. It works fine when just using `pandas`, but when using `dask` I get this error. I am on `Ubuntu`, `python 3.7.3` and `Dask 2.6.0`.

This is my error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "main.py", line 56, in  main(df=data, nlp=nlp, lang=lang, wanted_pos=wp)
>   File "main.py", line 13, in main df.persist()
>   File "/home/bertil/Envs/datascience/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 138, in persist (result,) = persist(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)
>   File "/home/bertil/Envs/datascience/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 629, in persist results = schedule(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
>   File "/home/bertil/Envs/datascience/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/threaded.py", line 80, in get **kwargs
>   File "/home/bertil/Envs/datascience/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 486, in get_async raise_exception(exc, tb)
>   File "/home/bertil/Envs/datascience/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 316, in reraise raise exc
>   File "/home/bertil/Envs/datascience/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 222, in execute_task result = _execute_task(task, data)
>   File "/home/bertil/Envs/datascience/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/core.py", line 118, in _execute_task args2 = [_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args]
>   File "/home/bertil/Envs/datascience/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/core.py", line 118, in  args2 = [_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args]
>   File "/home/bertil/Envs/datascience/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/core.py", line 119, in _execute_task return func(*args2)
>   TypeError: **call**() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pathlib import Path
import dask.dataframe as dd
import stanfordnlp
import string


def main(df, nlp, lang, wanted_pos):
    df['tagged'] = df['Message'].apply(process,
                                       args=(nlp, lang, wanted_pos,),
                                       meta=('Message', 'object'))
    df.persist()
    df.to_csv(f'output.csv')


def process(text, nlp, lang, wanted_pos):
    # Remove punctuation
    text = text.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
    token = nlp(text)
    words = {word for sent in token.sentences for word in sent.words}
    wanted_words = set(filter(lambda x: x in wanted_pos, words))
    wanted_words = ','.join(word for word in wanted_words if word)
    return wanted_words


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Choose language
    lang = 'da'

    # Chose wanted_pos
    wp = ['NOUN']

    # Read data in chunks
    data = dd.read_csv('sample.csv', quoting=3, error_bad_lines=False,
                       dtype={'Message': 'object',
                              'Action Time': 'object',
                              'ClientQueues': 'object',
                              'Country': 'object',
                              'Custom Tags': 'object',
                              'Favorites': 'object',
                              'Geo Target': 'object',
                              'Location': 'object',
                              'State': 'object'})



    # Download model for nlp.
    stanford_path = Path.home() / 'stanfordnlp_resources' / f'{lang}_ddt_models'
    if not stanford_path.exists():
        stanfordnlp.download(lang)

    # Set up nlp pipeline
    nlp = stanfordnlp.Pipeline(processors='tokenize,lemma,pos', lang=lang)

    main(df=data, nlp=nlp, lang=lang, wanted_pos=wp)
```

Update: I thought I had fixed it, but I hadn't, so I deleted my answer again. I am still experiencing the problem